# TWS API Modifying Order Not Working, Got Error 103 "Duplicate Order ID"

Tags: c++, interactive-brokers, tws

The API manual just gives conflict information:

> To modify an order, simply call the IBApi.EClient.placeOrder function again with the same parameters used to place the original order, except for the changed parameter. This includes the IBApi.Order.OrderId, which must match the IBApi.Order.OrderId of the original.

If you check IBApi.EClient.placeOrder function, you will find the following about order id:

> the order's unique identifier. Use a sequential id starting with the id received at the nextValidId method. If a new order is placed with an order ID less than or equal to the order ID of a previous order an error will occur.

This is my problem. When I tried to modify an order as instructed above, I got the error "Duplicate Order ID" and this is just as stated above about the order id.

So how do I modify the price or quantity of an open order?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite usual in my app too, and not always clear why. I suppose you used an OrderId elsewhere, which is higher than this one. This shouldn't invalidate the previously used order id, but sometimes does.

I solved the issue this way:

- Cancel the order
- Get a new order id by requesting nextValidId. Call reqIds(1);
- Create a new order with the same data (and make your modifications)
- Send a new order using the new id

Of course this does not modify the open order literally, but the result is the same.

Comment: In my case, I hope to modify the order because of the related order and position update and online database update. I trade very frequently. Thousands of orders a day. And the modification of the orders happens very frequently. To cancel and send new order will generate two many orders in my database. In addition, it might cause concurrency issue in my application.

Comment: Yes, I went trough this too, but I did not find any other solution. If an id considered 'duplicated' once, it remains duplicated and you have no options. I redesigned those related updates to go smoothly and quick.

Comment: What kind of concurrency issue is that? How it does not come if you modify only price, but it does if you modify id too? You have to resend the order anyway.

Comment: New order quantity is calculated according to the position size and unfilled orders. When I cancel an order and new order is not sent yet, another new order might be generated because of the cancellation, which causes the unfilled order amount dropped temporarily. This is still manageable. The issue I hate most the quantity of the orders in my database since I might need to cancel tens thousands of times a day.

Comment: Then the problem is more serious, and you have to rethink your strategy. IB does not allow thousands of cancellations because you overcharge their servers for zero commission. You'll get a polite reminder on the first day.

Comment: I don't know your app and your strategy. I'd keep the orders prepared, but not actually send them until it is (almost) sure they will executed immediately. This way there'd be only one order sent out at a time, and no more concurrency issue because of the id. Also, this prevents from getting "Duplicate order ID".

Comment: Janos, thanks a lot! I notice I can separate the IB orders from the orders on my database. So I can cancel and send new order with IB, but I can use the same order in my database. I just need to update the size and price in the database. Now I notice the cancellation didn't work and new orders were sent without problem so I got way more new orders on IB. Do you have any problem with cancelOrder function?

Comment: In my system, all orders sent to IB are ready for execution. If the system gets different calculation result before the orders are executed, the orders will be updated according to the latest result. Executed orders will affect the future calculation. The process is on-going and never ends. So my system trades very frequently but I am not doing HFT.

Comment: Yes I did, although not with the cancelOrder function itself. IB does not tolerate frequent placeOrder/cancelOrder requests. Maybe, it is the same with too frequent updates of an order, I'm not sure. First you'll receive a notification, later restrictions will be applied on your account. This is well understandable from IB point of view: you send excessive requests, but you pay commission for filled orders only. Be careful! I don't trade intraday, this experience comes from a bug in my app that caused frequent place/cancel.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way, but this works for me with these two conditions:

- Use client ID zero
- Bind past and future orders:

  ```
  ib.reqOpenOrders() // Bind previous opened orders
  ib.reqAutoOpenOrders()  // Bind all future orders
  ```

With this approach you don't need to cancel the order; you can just modify it.